# Background-Elevation not working after Android Studio update to Flamingo

Tags: android, android-studio, android-dialog, android-bottomsheetdialog

I have just updated my Android Studio to Flamingo and run the project on the device.

All AlertDialog and BottomSheetDialog Backgrounds are not working now. I didn't change the code. I tried to change the theme and background colour of dialog.

**What could be the reason?**

Please see the before and after UI screenshots.

**BottomSheetDialog** Before and After

[image: Before Update Android Studio] [image: After Update Android Stuido]

**AlertDialog** Before and After

[image: Before Update Android Studio] [image: After Update Android Stuido]

Here my AlertDialog code for reference.

```
fun showCustomProgressDialog(mContext: Context?): AlertDialog? {
            try {
                val factory = LayoutInflater.from(mContext)
                val customProgressBar: View = factory.inflate(R.layout.custom_progress_dialog, null)
                val customDialog = AlertDialog.Builder(mContext).create()
                customDialog.setView(customProgressBar)
                customDialog.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))
                customDialog.setCancelable(false)
                return customDialog
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
            return null
        }
```

**Update:** It is working fine in a real devices, still not working in Emulator.